# Merge Time Series in Apache Pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, time-series

I think my problem is trivial, but I'm new to Pig and I can't see an obvious answer in the documentation. I have two time series I wish to merge. Let's say one of them is just a stream of events `X`:

```
100 A
200 B
300 C
400 D
500 E
600 F
```

Then another one indicates when some state changes happen, call it `Y`.

```
 50 on
250 off
350 on
450 off
```

I would like to tag the first time series `X` with the current `on/off` status from `Y`. So specifically I want:

```
100 A on
200 B on
300 C off
400 D on
500 E off
600 F off
```

If I was writing this in another language I might do something like merge sort `X` and `Y` and take a single pass through it, remembering the last `on/off` status and tagging the `X` entries.

What is the best way to do this in Pig? I have received some existing code which uses a `JOIN` of `X` and `Y` and then filters it, but I think the data inflation caused by the join is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a very easy solution. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
X1 = Rank X;
Y1 = Rank Y;

XY = JOIN X1 BY BY $0 LEFT OUTER, Y1 BY $0;

SPLIT XY INTO status_known IF status is not null, status_unknown OTHERWISE;

--Y2: Find out last status in Y1 (with Group all, max)
--Y3: Cross status_unknown with Y2

UNION status_known and Y3
```